# Why does Controller 'Get' Edit method getting called twice in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have problem in edit view. When I debug my code, after `Id` is passed from `ShowCategory` view to `EditPostGroup` method in controller, it works correctly, but after page loads, `Id` zero is sent to the Edit method in controller and throws an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

This is my code: this method is in the `PostRepository` and get `postGroup` with `Id` from database :

```cs
    public PostGroupViewModel GetPostGroupById(int postGroupId)
    {
        var postGroup = _context.PostGroups.Find(postGroupId);

        PostGroupViewModel postGroupViewModel = new PostGroupViewModel()
        {
             GroupId = postGroup.GroupId,
             GroupTitle = postGroup.GroupTitle,
             GroupImageName = postGroup.GroupImageName,
             IsDelete =  postGroup.IsDelete,
             ParentId = postGroup.ParentId
        };

        return postGroupViewModel;
    }
```

These are `Get` and `Post` edit method in `CategoryController`:

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult EditPostGroup(int id)
    {
        var groups = _postService.GetGroupForManagePost();
        ViewData["Groups"] = new SelectList(groups, "Value", "Text");
        var postGroupViewModel = _postService.GetPostGroupById(id);
        return View(postGroupViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult EditPostGroup(PostGroup postGroup, IFormFile imgPostGroupUp)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View("EditPostGroup");

        _postService.UpdatePostGroup(postGroup, imgPostGroupUp);

        return RedirectToAction("ShowCategory", "Category");
    }
```

This is 'ShowCategory' View, It sends PostGroupId to Edit action method:

```html
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Category List";
       
    }
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h4 style="color:darkblue;" >Category List</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <br />
                
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin: 10px 0;">   
                        <a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="CreateCategory" asp-area="Admin" class="btn btn-outline btn-success">Create Category</a>               
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer text-center" id="dataTables-example" aria-describedby="dataTables-example_info">
                        <thead class="table-success black-ribon">
                            <tr>
                              
                                <th>Title</th>
                                <th>Parent Category</th>
                                <th>Image</th>
                                <th>Operations</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in  @ViewBag.CategoryList)
                        {
                            <tr>
                          
                                <td>
                                    @item.GroupTitle
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.ParentId
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <img class="thumbnail" style="width:40px;height:40px;"  src="/img/postGroup/@item.GroupTitle/@item.GroupImageName" alt="">
                                </td>
    
                                <td>
                                    <a href="/Admin/Category/EditPostGroup/@item.GroupId" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">
                                        Edit
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
    
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
```

This is the `EditPostGroupView`:

```html
    @model DataLayer.Models.ViewModels.PostGroup.PostGroupViewModel
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Post Edit";
        //Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
    }
    
    <div class="row">
        <form method="post" asp-action="EditPostGroup" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @* <input type="hidden" asp-for="GroupId" />*@
            @*<input type="hidden" asp-for="Post.PostImageName"/>*@
      
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h2>Category List</h2>
                <hr/>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="GroupTitle" class="form-control">
                    <span asp-validation-for="GroupTitle"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ParentId</label>
                    <select class="form-control" asp-for="ParentId" asp-items="@(ViewData["Groups"] as SelectList)">
                    <option value="">-- please select --</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="ParentId"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p></p>
                <img id="imgPost" class="thumbnail" src="img/postGroup/@Model.GroupTitle/@Model.GroupImageName"/>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Select Image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="imgPostGroupUp" id="imgPostGroupUp">
                </div> 
            </div> 
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-success"/>
        </form>
    </div>
        
    @section scripts
        {
        <script>    
            function readURL(input) {   
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
    
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#imgPost').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    }
    
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                }
            }
    
            $("#imgPostUp").change(function () {
                readURL(this);
            });
        </script>         
    }
```

This is the Routing in Program.cs:

```html
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "MyArea",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

This is PostGroup Model:

```html
public class PostGroup
    {
        [Key]
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        //public int? SubGroupId { get; set; }

        public string GroupTitle { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string? GroupImageName { get; set; }

        public bool IsDelete { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
        public  List<PostGroup>? PostGroups { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("PostGroup")]
        //[NotMapped]
        public  List<Post>? Posts { get; set; }
}
```

This is postGroupViewModel:

```html
public class PostGroupViewModel
    {
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
  
        public string GroupTitle { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string? GroupImageName { get; set; }

        public bool IsDelete { get; set; }

        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    }
```

What is the problem?

Could it be a problem with the `Program.cs` and middleware?

I changed `EditPostGroup(PostGroup postGroup, IFormFile imgPostGroupUp)` method to
`EditPostGroup(PostGroupViewModel postGroupViewModel, IFormFile imgPostGroupUp)`,but there is still a problem.

Comment: `after page loads, Id zero is sent` how is the page loaded? Using what URL? The method `EditPostGroup(int id)` expects to find an `id` parameter in the route or query parameters. If there's no such parameter, `id` will have its default value, 0

Comment: BTW `EditPostGroup` is a bad name for a GET method. Why not just name it `Get`, the way all tutorials show?

Comment: I debugged multiple times, when I click on edit button of row ,Id is sent correctly to the Edit method in controller and also it gets PostGroup Info correctly, but when page is loading, Id zero is sent to the controller again.

Comment: @n.e: The following lines `if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View("EditPostGroup");`  in the `public IActionResult EditPostGroup(PostGroup postGroup, IFormFile imgPostGroupUp)` action method causing the _object reference not set to an instance of an object_ error. Your strongly typed view is using `PostGroupViewModel` type, but after processing the *HTTPPOST* request if the model does not valid the `return View("EditPostGroup");` line is rendering the view without passing the view data model.

Comment: @n.e: You didn't include all related parts of code. But I suppose `EditPostGroup(PostGroup postGroup, IFormFile imgPostGroupUp)` action method should use the same  `PostGroupViewModel` data type instead of `PostGroup ` and if the `ModelState.IsValid` returns `false` it is necessary call `return View("EditPostGroup",  postGroup)`, there `postGroup` is `PostGroupViewModel` type.

Comment: I debugged again  with EditPostGroup(PostGroupViewModel postGroupViewModel , IFormFile imgPostGroupUp) action method , but it still sends zero ID.

Comment: This happens before sending the edited data to the database.

Comment: you commented out `@* <input type="hidden" asp-for="GroupId" />*@`. What's the reason for that?

Comment: Hi @n.e, ok from your comment you mean your problem is `PostGroup` post method cannot receive the value of the parameters, right? How is your received data like? Do they all null or count=0, pls share the screenshot to us. Besides, how is your PostGroupViewModel model like?

Comment: Hi @Rena, the problem is in the 'Get' EditPostGroup action method and its view loading. For first time , Id is sent to the controller correctly, but after page loads, Id is sent to 'Get' action method again, with Id Zero.

Comment: @n.e: **1)** Can you put a break point on the `return View("EditPostGroup");` line and check that `Id` is `0` when the view is rendering after executing this line? Check if it is? **2)** You didn't include all related parts of code. Add declaration of the `PostGroupViewModel` and the  `PostGroup` to the post. This might be helpful to understand where the problem is.

Comment: @Victor, I put break point on the return View("EditPostGroup"); Id isn't 0 when the view is rendering.

Comment: @n.e: So, you hit break-point on the `return View("EditPostGroup");` line. At this moment `postGroup.Id` isn't `0`. But when you step into the `EditPostGroup` view the `@Model.Id` does equal `0`. Am I understand correct? This is the problem?

Comment: @Victro, yes that's right.

Comment: @n.e: Then see answer in my first two comments. You MUST replace the `return View("EditPostGroup");` line by `return View("EditPostGroup",  postGroup);` and the `postGroup` MUST be `PostGroupViewModel` type. **You should fix code to pass the data model to the view. When you don't pass the data model then all properties have default value: `0`, `null` etc.**

Comment: @Victor, you mean, return View("EditPostGroup") in Post action method change to return View("EditPostGroup",  postGroup) ???

Comment: @n.e: Correct. And the `postGroup` should be `PostGroupViewModel` type, because of this type is declared in the first line of the `EditPostGroup.cshtml`. This is how the ASP.NET MVC binding works.

Comment: return View("EditPostGroup") is for when ModelState is not valid, and this action 
 method runs after edit.

Comment: @Victor, I posted PostGroup and PostGroupViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query string instead of passing the id in .net core:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit()
    {
        string id = HttpContext.Request.Query["id"].ToString();
        var model = await _service.FindAsync(int.Parse(id));
        return View(model);
    }
```

in razor view:

```
<a href="/service/edit?id=@item.ServiceId">
```

Also, using # in the src of a file in razor view causes this problem. remove it or give it a value.

```
<img id="img-master" class="thumbnail" src="#" />
```

to

```
<img id="img-master" class="thumbnail" src="/images/@Model.ImageEdit" />
```